# Fetch html page via axios return error 301/302

Tags: node.js, axios, http-status-code-302

I want to fetch a page HTML but every time I try to fetch either for HTTP or HTTPS I get a response either error 301 or 302.

Already tried add a proxy http and socks5 neither helped

```js
axios("https://www.macys.com", {
  method: "GET",
  maxRedirects: 1,
  headers: {
    Accept: "*/*",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0",
  },
});
```

error:

```
Error [ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]: Maximum number of redirects exceeded
```

if I set max redirects to 0

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 302".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

And if I set max redirects to 1000 it's just loaded infinitely

An interesting fact with postman it works fine

Comment: Have you considered removing the `maxRedirects` option to see if it at least unblocks you?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Please [edit] your question to provide the actual code

Comment: if I remove maxredirects it just keeps loading infinitly

Answer (score 0):

For someone that's facing the same problem, this is probably not the best approach but I managed to fix it with `puppeteer`

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    });
    console.log(await page.content()); //our html
    await browser.close();
```

Comment: puppeteer causes server overload recently

Comment: Yeah, you're right I changed to use page's instead, load page -> get content -> close page. You can go even further and don't close the page and get the tab by name to get the content in case of some static content.